# WKWebView on iOS generates LayoutConstraints error when keyboard appears

Tags: keyboard, wkwebview, nslayoutconstraint

I have built a simple iOS app that displays a full-screen WKWebView. It works fine as long as there is no input that triggers the onscreen keyboard but as soon as the keyboard appears it generates an error "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" and a whole trace of NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints.

Despite the error, the keyboard appears and I can use the text input.

My app is very simple, it just has this app delegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = WebViewController()
        return true
    }

}
```

and this view controller:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let webView = WKWebView()

        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")!)

        webView.load(request)
    }

}
```

Is there something wrong with the way I use the anchors on the webview? Or do I need extra constraints to handle the onscreen keyboard?

Comment: No solution, but I submitted my app to the appstore and it was accepted by Apple. So I guess it's ok to ignore errors generated by WKWebView.

Comment: I've had the same issue for a long time and have been ignoring it. Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: No, I never fixed it. I submitted my app as it was and it was accepted by Apple. I guess everybody just ignores this error.